# Angular. Выбрасывает после обращения к сайту

Tags: node.js, angularjs, npm

```
andrey@DESKTOP-5UVHVST MINGW64 /d/code/js/phone/angular-phonecat (master)
$ npm start

> angular-phonecat@0.0.0 prestart D:\code\js\phone\angular-phonecat
> npm install


> angular-phonecat@0.0.0 postinstall D:\code\js\phone\angular-phonecat
> bower install


> angular-phonecat@0.0.0 start D:\code\js\phone\angular-phonecat
> http-server -a 0.0.0.0 -p 8000

Starting up http-server, serving ./ on port: 8000
Hit CTRL-C to stop the server
[Wed, 13 Apr 2016 09:33:51 GMT] "GET /" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.112 Safari/537.36"
_http_outgoing.js:351
      throw new TypeError('The header content contains invalid characters');
      ^

TypeError: The header content contains invalid characters
    at ServerResponse.OutgoingMessage.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:351:13)
    at ResponseStream.(anonymous function) [as setHeader] (D:\CODE\JS\phone\angular-phonecat\node_modules\http-server\node_modules\union\lib\response-stream.js:86:34)
    at D:\CODE\JS\phone\angular-phonecat\node_modules\http-server\node_modules\ecstatic\lib\ecstatic\showdir.js:42:13
    at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:82:15)

npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.10586
npm ERR! argv "D:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "D:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "start"
npm ERR! node v4.4.3
npm ERR! npm  v2.15.1
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! angular-phonecat@0.0.0 start: `http-server -a 0.0.0.0 -p 8000`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the angular-phonecat@0.0.0 start script 'http-server -a 0.0.0.0 -p 8000'.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the angular-phonecat package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     http-server -a 0.0.0.0 -p 8000
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs angular-phonecat
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!
npm ERR!     npm owner ls angular-phonecat
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     D:\code\js\phone\angular-phonecat\npm-debug.log
```

Comment: проверьте что за Headers вы пытаетесь установить

Comment: @Grundy как это можно сделать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У меня тоже была проблема долго все перепробовал помогло вот что зайди в путь

> angular-phonecat\node_modules\http-server\node_modules\ecstatic\lib\ecstatic

и в файле etag.js замени на это:

```
module.exports = function (stat) {
  return JSON.stringify([stat.ino, stat.size, stat.mtime.toJSON()].join('-'));
}
```

мне помогло, говорят что в последней версии http-server это исправлено.

Answer (score 1):

Эта проблема у меня лично была связана с npm пакетом "karma", когда использовалась не en-en локаль. В этом случае надо было идти в "node_modules/karma/lib/middleware/commonjs" и удалять или комментировать 76-ю сточку

```
response.setHeader('Expires', (new Date(0)).toString())
```

ну либо подправлять, чтобы оно генерило строку без латинских литер.